# Getting crash on selecting current date and year when pressing ok button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, date

I have one picker date. When ever i change the date and showing. Its working fine. But if i not change any date and press ok button. Getting crash.Here is my code :

```
NSDate *reportingDate;
 NSDateFormatter *pickerDateFormatter;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [self updatePickerUI];
}

- (void)updatePickerUI {
    _pickerView.hidden = true;
    self.picker.monthPickerDelegate = self;
    self.picker.maximumYear = 2115;
    self.picker.minimumYear = 1900;
    self.picker.yearFirst = YES;
    NSString *mon = [userDefault objectForKey:@"monthText"];
    NSString *yr = [userDefault objectForKey:@"YearText"];

     NSLog(@"%@%@", mon,yr);
    self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@,%@", mon, yr];
}

- (NSString*)formatDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    if (pickerDateFormatter == nil) {
        pickerDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    pickerDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM, yyyy";
    return [pickerDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
- (void)monthPickerDidChangeDate:(SRMonthPicker *)monthPicker
{
    reportingDate = monthPicker.date;
    NSString *selectedDate = [self formatDate:reportingDate];
    [self updateDateLabel:selectedDate];
}
```

Okay button action :

```
 - (IBAction)pickerAction:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
            if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
                return;
            }
        }
     NSDate *pickerDate = reportingDate;
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:pickerDate];
        NSInteger reportingMonth = [components month];
        NSInteger reportingYear = [components year];

 NSString *Month = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)reportingMonth];
    NSString *Yrs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)reportingYear];
    NSString *temp = @"0";
    if (Month.length == 1) {
        SelMonth = [temp stringByAppendingString:Month];
    }else {
        SelMonth = Month;
    }
    [str setObject:SelMonth forKey:@"month"];
    [str setObject:Yrs forKey:@"year"];
    NSString *Mont =  [self MonthNameString:[SelMonth integerValue]];
    }
```

Crash on here this line :

> NSInteger reportingMonth = [components month];
>       NSInteger reportingYear = [components year];

Thanks

Comment: Getting a crash? Is there a crash log in console? That could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting `reportingDate` property in `monthPickerDidChangeDate:` method. So it will get invoked and set value to `reportingDate` only when changing the date in picker. Set a default/selected value to `reportingDate` property on displaying the picker will resolved your issue.

or try this if you just need to avoid the crash,

```
- (IBAction)pickerAction:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
            return;
        }
    }
    if (reportingDate != nil) { //add a nil check here
         NSDate *pickerDate = reportingDate;
         NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
         NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:pickerDate];
         NSInteger reportingMonth = [components month];
         NSInteger reportingYear = [components year];
         NSDate *pickerDate = reportingDate;
         NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
         NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:pickerDate];
         NSInteger reportingMonth = [components month];
         NSInteger reportingYear = [components year];

         NSString *Month = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)reportingMonth];
         NSString *Yrs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)reportingYear];
         NSString *temp = @"0";
         if (Month.length == 1) {
             SelMonth = [temp stringByAppendingString:Month];
         }else {
             SelMonth = Month;
         }
         [str setObject:SelMonth forKey:@"month"];
         [str setObject:Yrs forKey:@"year"];
         NSLog(@"%@", SelMonth);
         NSString *Mont =  [self MonthNameString:[SelMonth integerValue]];
    }

}
```

Comment: Which means, if date is not moved and if user tap on ok button, current year, month will pass values ?

Comment: still i am getting crash `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 11]'`

Comment: if the user opens the picker for the first time and clicked ok without changing date on the picker, `reportingDate` will be nil. So you either need to set a default value to it or add nil check to avoid the crash.

Comment: did you added the nil check in `pickerAction` method? if yes this might be another issue. in which line you are getting crash?

Comment: i  have updated my code.the crash is this line `NSString *Mont =  [self MonthNameString:[SelMonth integerValue]];`

Comment: try moving all those login inside `if (reportingDate != nil)` this if condition and see the log of `NSLog(@"%@", SelMonth);`